# C# datetime formats

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

**when i am using the following command 
I am getting wrong output of month**

```
label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

plz help me

what else shall I add If my query is that much simple

Comment: Try  dd/MM/yyyy your MM needs to be uppercase

Comment: So what is the output and what should it have been?

Answer (score 1):

Its MM, not mm. mm means minutes.

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit:**
It is wise to study the Custom Date and Time Format Strings to grasp a better understanding of what you are and are not able to do with the Date Time formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only problem is that mm must be up case.

Answer (score 0):

Lower `mm` means minutes, so

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```